# What are the advantages of using Blogger's HTTPS with custom domain?

Tags: google, https, blogger, cloudflare

[Blogger's HTTPS](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6284029) is now available for custom domains too.

I am currently using [Cloudflare SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/) and they automatically apply it to all HTTP requests, and changes "http" to "https" for all resources or links on my blog.

Are there any advantages in using Blogger's own HTTPS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real advantage over using bloggers, letsencrypted or Cloudflare, they are all free and do the job. However there is a [difference between using free certification and ones that cost](https://moz.com/blog/traditional-vs-lets-encrypt-vs-cloudflare) money.

If you intend to use the Cloudflare SSL and If you care about your users then you should enable both the HTTPS at Bloggers and Cloudflare, then within the Cloudflare Dashboard and within Crypto you set it to [Full (strict)](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-) otherwise your site is only encrypted from user to Cloudflare which is a false impression of security.

Generally I prefer using SSL on the orginin server (your case blogger) and then Cloudflare SSL in full (strict) mode.